# Laravel LDAPRecord issue with Organization Unit

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I have a slight problem with `LDAPRecord` in `Laravel` when trying to authenticate users.
I managed to enable `LDAP` authentication on my website, when a user enters credentials then I can authenticate against `dc=my_org_domain,dc=com'`. But this will allow all users in `AD` to access my website. To control them I have to use [Restricting Login](https://ldaprecord.com/docs/laravel/v2/auth/restricting-login/#using-an-organizational-unit).

Everything works if I use a query like this:

```
$query->in('dc=my_org_domain,dc=com');
```

but my actual group looks like that:

```
$query->in('CN=My-App-Login,OU=SecurityGroups,DC=my_org_domain,DC=com');
```

But it works in another application written in `raw` `PHP`.

How can I fix this or debug it?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the method for restricting to users in an Organizational Unit (OU), but you're trying to do it with a group, so that won't work.

That same page you linked to shows [how to do it with a group](https://ldaprecord.com/docs/laravel/v2/auth/restricting-login/#using-a-group-membership), that is, create an authentication rule (as it shows you how to do) and define your `isValid` function. I suggest you use the option to [check for membership recursively](https://ldaprecord.com/docs/laravel/v2/auth/restricting-login/#checking-for-nested-groups-recursively) so that you can put other groups inside your main group:

```
public function isValid()
{
    return $this->user->groups()->recursive()->exists('CN=My-App-Login,OU=SecurityGroups,DC=my_org_domain,DC=com');
}
```